# How to use Hibernate to combine efficient queries on @ManyToMany association?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities with a `ManyToMany` association between them - `FeedbackApp` & `FeedbackAppProfile` and each of them has a `tenant-id` FK to `Tenant` entity.

FeedbackApp entity:

```
public class FeedbackApp {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
       
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
    private Tenant tenant;

    /*
        Marked as the owner side.
     */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "feedbackApp_profile_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "feedbackApp_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id"))
    Set<FeedbackProfile> profiles;
}
```

The FeedbackProfile entity:

```
public class FeedbackProfile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
    private Tenant tenant;

    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "profiles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<FeedbackApp> feedbackApps;
}
```

The `feedbackApp_profile_mapping` join table has 2 columns and looks like this:
[image]

**My question**: I need to create a query that gets all feedback apps for a specific feedback profile and tenant id. Is it possible to get it with Hibernate/JPA OR I have to manually query my join table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GabiM direction, I created a `join fetch` query which did the job for what I needed:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT f FROM FeedbackApp f JOIN FETCH f.profiles p WHERE p.id = ?1 AND p.tenant.id = ?2")
    Set<FeedbackApp> getFeedbackAppsByProfileId(long profileId, long tenantId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let Jpa worry about the optimal Sql query to generate. Your Jpa/criteria/specification query should be something like

`select fp.feedbackApps from FeedbackProfile fp LEFT JOIN FETCH fp.feedbackApps where fp.id=:feedback_profile_id and fp.tenant.id=:tenant_id`

Since you are asking about efficiency, better remove `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` from the two many-to-many mappings and use `join fetch` or named [entity graphs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs001.htm) to do the joins only when you need to.